# Using spawn function with NODE_ENV=production

Tags: node.js

I'm currently trying to run process using `spawn`. What I am trying to run from shell is the following;

`NODE_ENV=production node app/app.js`

Here's the code to run that;

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var start = spawn('NODE_ENV=production',['node','app/app.js']);
```

However, I got the following error;

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

How can I do that using `spawn` ?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

**Your [usage of spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) is not correct**:

> `spawn( command, args, options )`:
>
> Launches a new process with the given command, with command line arguments in args. If omitted, args defaults to an empty Array.
>
> The third argument is used to specify additional options, which defaults to:
>
> { cwd: undefined, env: process.env }
>
> Use env to specify environment variables that will be visible to the new process, the default is process.env.

So **the env variable `NODE_ENV` should be provided on the options argument**:

```js
// ES6 Object spread eases extending process.env
spawn( 'node', ['app.js'], { env: { ...process.env, NODE_ENV: 'test' } })
```

See also [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-to-debug-any-node-js-child-process-error-spawn-enoent)

Comment: With ES6/7 Stage 3 syntax you can do this in one line using object spread syntax - `spawn('node', ['app.js'], {...process.env, NODE_ENV: 'test})`

Answer (score 16):

Syntax: spawn(command, [args], [options])

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var start = spawn('node', ['app.js'], {env: {NODE_ENV: 'production'}});
```

Or keep default ENV variables:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var productionEnv = process.env; // TODO should clone process.env like utils.extend
productionEnv.NODE_ENV = 'production';

var start = spawn('node', ['app.js'], {env: productionEnv});
```

---

My test:

app.js

```
console.log(process.env);
```

spawn.js

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var start = spawn('node', ['app.js'], {env: {NODE_ENV: 'production'}});

start.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

from terminal:

```
node spawn
```

output:

```
{ NODE_ENV: 'production' }
```

Comment: I have test this on my server, are you sure you can run `node` from terminal?

Comment: I'm running from iterm, when I use `console.log(process.env)`, it gives iterm environment variables.

Comment: If you want to use the parent process' environment, just leave it undefined.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var productionEnv = Object.create(process.env);
productionEnv.NODE_ENV = 'production';
var start = spawn('node', ['app.js'], {env: productionEnv});
```

this did not

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var start = spawn('node', ['app.js'], {env: {NODE_ENV: 'production'}});
```

Comment: I don't understand anything.  I have this console.log: `console.log({ NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV, env: process.env })`, and NODE_ENV gives 'development', but env is an object that has NODE_ENV as 'production'. I don't understand what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

add shell option worked for me

```
gulp.task('xxx', function (callback) {
    process.chdir('xxx/');
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var productionEnv = Object.create(process.env);
    // var jekyll = spawn('gulp', ['stylecheck'], {stdio: 'inherit', env: productionEnv});
    var jekyll = spawn('gulp', ['stylecheck'], {stdio: 'inherit', env: productionEnv, shell: true});

    jekyll.on('exit', function (code) {
        console.log(arguments);
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: see nodejs api: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows

Comment: You just copied and pasted the code which doesn't explained well. Looks like better one but please explain it

Comment: this nodes official docs may help: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options