# How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?

Tags: node.js, debugging, error-handling, child-process, spawn

### When I get the following error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:791:34)
```

### What procedure can I follow to fix it?

**Author note**: Lots of issues with this error encouraged me to post this question for future references.

**Related questions:**

- [using spawn function with NODE_ENV=production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825157/using-spawn-function-with-node-env-production)
- [node.js child_process.spawn ENOENT error - only under supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496015/node-js-child-process-spawn-enoent-error-only-under-supervisord)
- [spawn ENOENT node.js error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090140/spawn-enoent-node-js-error)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603713/nodejs-spawn-enoent-error-on-travis-calling-global-npm-package
- [Node JS - child_process spawn('npm install') in Grunt task results in ENOENT error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156067/node-js-child-process-spawnnpm-install-in-grunt-task-results-in-enoent-err)
- [Running "foreman" task Fatal error: spawn ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366113/running-foreman-task-fatal-error-spawn-enoent/27689089#27689089)
- [unhandled error event in node js Error: spawn ENOENT at errnoException (child_process.js:975:11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26624302/unhandled-error-event-in-node-js-error-spawn-enoent-at-errnoexception-child-pr/27689141#27689141)
- [Node.js SpookyJS: error executing hello.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379677/node-js-spookyjs-error-executing-hello-js)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572214/run-grunt-on-a-directory-nodewebkit
- [Run exe file with Child Process NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764429/run-exe-file-with-child-process-nodejs)
- [Node: child_process.spawn not working on Java even though it's in the path (ENOENT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717446/node-child-process-spawn-not-working-on-java-even-though-its-in-the-path-enoe)
- [spawn ENOENT error with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232590/spawn-enoent-error-with-nodejs) (PYTHON related)
- [image resizing is not working in node.js (partial.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346717/image-resizing-is-not-working-in-node-js-partial-js) (non-installed dependency)
- [npm install error ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924494/npm-install-error-enoent) (build dependency problem)
- [Cannot install node.js - oracle module on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393631/cannot-install-node-js-oracle-module-on-windows-7) (build dependency problem)
- [Error installing gulp using nodejs on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699999/error-installing-gulp-using-nodejs-on-windows) (strange case)

Comment: In my case, I was passing in the whole command as a String like you would with `exec` instead of passing in the command as the first argument and the options as an Array for the second argument. e.g. I was doing `spawn( "adb logcat -c" )` instead of `spawn( "adb", [ "logcat", "-c" ] )`.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65008091/8119511

Comment: In VS Code, uninstalled below linter extension, then it worked: marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fnando.linter . See https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5275#issuecomment-1250079916

Comment: Again, a _missing dependency within environment_ cause

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## How to research the spawn call raising the error:

- [Use NODE_DEBUG=child_process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474965/1894803), Credits to @karl-richter. *Simple, quick, October 2019*
- [Use a wrapper to decorate `child_process.spawn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883443/1894803), Credits to @jiaji-zhou. *Simple, quick, January 2015*
- [Long procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27688805/1894803), credits to @laconbass. *Complex, time-cost, December 2014*

## Known, usual causes

1. Environment issues

   - The command executable does not exist within the system (dependency not being installed). *see [prominc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30811285/1894803)*
   - The command executable does not exist within a directory of those specified by `PATH` environment variable.
   - The executable binary was compiled with uncompatible libraries. *see [danilo-ramirez answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501580/1894803)*
2. Windows-only bugs/quirks

   - '.cmd' extension / shell: true. *see [li-zheng answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6318705/li-zheng)*
   - Administrator permisions. *see [steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61567274/1894803)*
3. Wrong `spawn('command', ['--argument', 'list'], { cwd, env, ...opts })` usage

   - Specified working directory (`opts.cwd`) does not exist · *see [leeroy-brun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37884459/1894803)*
   - Argument list within command `String` <s>`spawn('command --wrong --argument list')`</s>
   - Env vars within command string <s>`spawn('ENV_VAR=WRONG command')`</s>
   - Argument list `Array` specified as `String` <s>`spawn('cmd', '--argument list')`</s>
   - Unset `PATH` env variable <s>`spawn('cmd', [], { env: { variable } }`</s> => `spawn('cmd', [], { env: { ...process.env, variable } }`

---

> ### There are 2 posible origins for `ENOENT`:
>
> 1. Code you are writing
> 2. Code you depend on
>
> When origin is code you depend on, usual cause is an **Environment Issue** (or windows quirk)

---

Comment: I was executing execa with "ab" command, but "Apache Bench" was not installed in the container... So, the first "Environment Issues" case...

Answer (score 306):

NOTE: This error is almost always caused because the command does not exist, because the working directory does not exist, or from a windows-only bug.

I found a particular easy way to get the idea of the root cause of:

```
Error: spawn ENOENT
```

The problem of this error is, there is really little information in the error message to tell you where the call site is, i.e. which executable/command is not found, especially when you have a large code base where there are a lot of spawn calls. On the other hand, if we know the exact command that cause the error then we can follow [@laconbass' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27688805/916892) to fix the problem.

I found a very easy way to spot which command cause the problem rather than adding event listeners everywhere in your code as suggested in @laconbass' answer. The key idea is to wrap the original spawn call with a wrapper which prints the arguments send to the spawn call.

Here is the wrapper function, put it at the top of the `index.js` or whatever your server's starting script.

```
(function() {
    var childProcess = require("child_process");
    var oldSpawn = childProcess.spawn;
    function mySpawn() {
        console.log('spawn called');
        console.log(arguments);
        var result = oldSpawn.apply(this, arguments);
        return result;
    }
    childProcess.spawn = mySpawn;
})();
```

Then the next time you run your application, before the uncaught exception's message you will see something like that:

```
spawn called
{ '0': 'hg',
  '1': [],
  '2':
   { cwd: '/* omitted */',
     env: { IP: '0.0.0.0' },
     args: [] } }
```

In this way you can easily know which command actually is executed and then you can find out why nodejs cannot find the executable to fix the problem.

Comment: Here's another idea: just change `spawn()` to `exec()` and try again. `exec()` will tell you what command it _tried_ to run.

Comment: Important: Make sure to place the code above as close to the start of the main JS file as possible.  If you load other modules first, they can stash away the 'spawn' function and the override here will never be called.

Comment: I have no luck using the script. It doesn't work at all.

Comment: So how would you use this method in a grunt file? I'm not sure where to put this.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. I just put this at the top of my gulpfile.js file, and bingo bango bongo, spawn logging!

Comment: This is called as monkey patching ! :)

Comment: Hmm... Didn't work for me. Placed it at the top of `gulpfile.js`

Comment: Replace `console.log(arguments)` with `console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments, null, 4))` in case of nested (non-circular) objects that you want to print

Comment: `the command does not exist` agree, or sometimes even when it does exist but only as an alias

Comment: The first two lines of this answer fixed my problem!

Answer (score 159):

### Step 1: Ensure `spawn` is called the right way

First, review the [docs for child_process.spawn( command, args, options )](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

> Launches a new process with the given `command`, with command line arguments in `args`. If omitted, `args` defaults to an empty Array.
>
> The third argument is used to specify additional options, which defaults to:
>
> `{ cwd: undefined, env: process.env }`
>
> Use `env` to specify environment variables that will be visible to the new process, the default is `process.env`.

**Ensure you are not putting any command line arguments in `command` and the whole `spawn` call is valid**. Proceed to next step.

### Step 2: Identify the Event Emitter that emits the error event

Search on your source code for each call to `spawn`, or `child_process.spawn`, i.e.

```js
spawn('some-command', [ '--help' ]);
```

and attach there an event listener for the 'error' event, so you get noticed the exact Event Emitter that is throwing it as 'Unhandled'. After debugging, that handler can be removed.

```js
spawn('some-command', [ '--help' ])
  .on('error', function( err ){ throw err })
;
```

Execute and you should get the file path and line number where your 'error' listener was registered. Something like:

```
/file/that/registers/the/error/listener.js:29
      throw err;
            ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1000:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:791:34)
```

If the first two lines are still

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

do this step again until they are not. **You must identify the listener that emits the error before going on next step.**

### Step 3: Ensure the environment variable `$PATH` is set

There are two possible scenarios:

1. You rely on the default `spawn` behaviour, so child process environment will be the same as `process.env`.
2. You are explicity passing an `env` object to `spawn` on the `options` argument.

**In both scenarios, you must inspect the `PATH` key on the environment object that the spawned child process will use.**

*Example for scenario 1*

```javascript
// inspect the PATH key on process.env
console.log( process.env.PATH );
spawn('some-command', ['--help']);
```

*Example for scenario 2*

```javascript
var env = getEnvKeyValuePairsSomeHow();
// inspect the PATH key on the env object
console.log( env.PATH );
spawn('some-command', ['--help'], { env: env });
```

**The absence of `PATH` (i.e., it's `undefined`) will cause `spawn` to emit the `ENOENT` error**, as it will not be possible to locate any `command` unless it's an absolute path to the executable file.

**When `PATH` is correctly set, proceed to next step.** It should be a directory, or a list of directories. Last case is the usual.

### Step 4: Ensure `command` exists on a directory of those defined in `PATH`

**Spawn may emit the `ENOENT` error if the filename `command` (i.e, 'some-command') does not exist in at least one of the directories defined on `PATH`.**

Locate the exact place of `command`. On most linux distributions, this can be done from a terminal with the `which` command. It will tell you the absolute path to the executable file (like above), or tell if it's not found.

*Example usage of which and its output when a command is **found***

```
> which some-command
some-command is /usr/bin/some-command
```

*Example usage of which and its output when a command is **not found***

```
> which some-command
bash: type: some-command: not found
```

**miss-installed programs are the most common cause for a *not found* command.** Refer to each command documentation if needed and install it.

**When command is a simple script file ensure it's accessible from a directory on the `PATH`.** If it's not, either move it to one or make a link to it.

Once you determine `PATH` is correctly set and `command` is accessible from it, you should be able to spawn your child process without `spawn ENOENT` being thrown.

Comment: The problem for me was indeed that `PATH` was undefined. Do you know what causes this? I asked a question about it as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652582/process-env-path-undefined-in-passenger-node-app-production-mode

Comment: I remember a time it was `undefined` because the way I was spawning the node proccess.

Comment: This has been very helpful to my debugging of Spawn ENOENT. I've referenced it multiple times. Thanks!

Comment: if it's an ENOENT error, why would the command not be recognized on the OS? it seems reasonable that the command is recognized but something is wrong with reading the file itself...

Comment: @AlexMills Usually the situation you describe is reported as EACCES

Comment: I've also found that ENOENT will be thrown if you specify `cwd` in the options, but the given directory does not exist.

Comment: @DanielImfeld TOTAL SAVIOUR.  You should write an answer that says this.

Comment: I have a linux box and an osx box, both node versions reporting using v4.2.4.

On the OSX machine if a try/catch wrap a call to spawn('bogus-binary', ...), it lands in the catch statement.  in the linux box, it shows up in the event emitter.  this is wild.

Comment: @cdaringe please post a new question with the code and let's see what the problem may be

Comment: When you are using `spawn('some-command', ['--help'], { env: env });` as exemplified by Step 3 in this answer and are passing a custom environment, be sure to specify the `PATH`, for instance: `{ env: { PATH: process.env.PATH } }`. The env option will not inherit variables from your current env by default.

Comment: I was running the command as root/ with sudo so the `PATH` environment variable was not the same. Step 3 was the step that pointed this out to me. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by passing `shell: true` to the spawn options.

Comment: Also, if your Node process is running inside a container like Docker, make sure the command you're trying to run has been added to the Dockerfile

Comment: Another issue is that `shell` MUST be a simple file path with no arguments. To setup a shell like Docker or similar where args need to be passed it must be wrapped in a proxy bash script.

Comment: @MrYellow see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551786/1894803

Comment: @laconbass Yeah that overloading of `spawn` works, although the call in my case was buried within a module, made sense to use a bash script (which cleanly accepted `-c command` only) to call the actual shell with arguments (`innershell --foo $1 "$2"`) rather than monkey patching it deeply within the JS.

Comment: @MrYellow NODE_DEBUG=child_process may also help avoiding the monkey-patching solution => https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474965/1894803

Comment: `miss-installed programs` or non-interoperable installations (even when both may follow the documentation). Example: I installed python via `amazon-linux-extras` on `Amazon Linux 2` but it installed to the entity `python3.8` where `PythonShell` library for `Node` expected to invoke `python3`. I aliased the first to the second and continued failure. Now, change the installation to directly `yum install python3` and remove the alias - no issue anymore.

Comment: you did beat ChatGPT.. it couldn't help, thought I didn't have command. Apparently I was calling spawn incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Humans instruct machines. Remember that ;)

Comment: @DanielImfeld I was running a script where a child process spawn was changing the git branch and then tried to pull from the new branch. Since the script didn't exist in the new branch, I was getting this error (only on Debian, it was working on Macos). Your comment saved me a lot of headache. Thank you!

Comment: Another gotcha : `spawn` does not respect your bash settings. I had aliased a common build command, and node did not know about the alias. If you're seeing ENOENT, ensure your command is not an alias.

Answer (score 105):

simply adding `shell: true` option solved my problem:

following code is buggy on windows:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('dir');
```

workaround:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const child = spawn('dir', [], {shell: true});
```

based on [Node.js Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) (thanks to @Boris comment):

**Note that:**

> if the shell option is enabled, do not pass unsanitized user input to
> this function. Any input containing shell metacharacters may be used
> to trigger arbitrary command execution.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue, no need to define cmd or path

Comment: Adding `{ shell: true }` works on MacOS as well.

Comment: Finally resolved my issue after a day! Was operating out of windows and this solved it, thank you so much.

Comment: Note [that](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) "if the shell option is enabled, do not pass unsanitized user input to this function. Any input containing shell metacharacters may be used to trigger arbitrary command execution."

Comment: That's what fixed my issue, on windows, it couldn't find `eslint` ... thank you so much :)

Comment: Note this is a windows-only quirk. ENOENT may be thrown on other situations

Answer (score 46):

As [@DanielImfeld pointed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js#comment55397048_27688805), ENOENT will be thrown if you specify "cwd" in the options, but the given directory does not exist.

Comment: so is there a way to execute in a specific directory the command?

Comment: In Windows (7) it seems you also need to include the drive letter in the `cwd` path: 'c:/...' and not just '/...'

Answer (score 33):

Windows solution: Replace `spawn` with [node-cross-spawn](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn). For instance like this at the beginning of your app.js:

```
(function() {
    var childProcess = require("child_process");
    childProcess.spawn = require('cross-spawn');
})();
```

Comment: worked except it is a drop-in, no need for child_process. Exactly the same way as node's spawn or spawnSync, so it's a drop in replacement. `var spawn = require('cross-spawn');`

`// Spawn NPM asynchronously
var child = spawn('npm', ['list', '-g', '-depth', '0'], { stdio: 'inherit' });`

Answer (score 32):

@laconbass's answer helped me and is probably most correct.

I came here because I was using spawn incorrectly.
As a simple example:

*this is incorrect:*

```
const s = cp.spawn('npm install -D suman', [], {
    cwd: root
});
```

*this is incorrect:*

```
const s = cp.spawn('npm', ['install -D suman'], {
    cwd: root
});
```

**this is correct:**

```
const s = cp.spawn('npm', ['install','-D','suman'], {
    cwd: root
});
```

however, I recommend doing it this way:

```
const s = cp.spawn('bash');
s.stdin.end(`cd "${root}" && npm install -D suman`);
s.once('exit', code => {
   // exit
});
```

this is because then the `cp.on('exit', fn)` event will always fire, as long as bash is installed, otherwise, the `cp.on('error', fn)` event might fire first, if we use it the first way, if we launch 'npm' directly.

Comment: Thinking on refactoring my answer to provide a "general guide", and leaving details to each cause of the problem (miss dependencies, incorrect calls, wrong environment,...).

Comment: everyone who likes this answer, may also be interested in this native alternative: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/7bf225f0045b4649de6848f1ea5def4c

Comment: Downvoted because if what you want to have is a shell then you should use `child_process.exec` or pass `shell: true` to `spawn`.

Comment: @givanse not necessarily true - you may want to run zsh or bash or fsh depending on what shell you want to use, and the behavior is also different

Answer (score 32):

For ENOENT on Windows, https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2318#issuecomment-249355505 fix it.

e.g. replace spawn('npm', ['-v'], {stdio: 'inherit'}) with:

- for all node.js version:

  ```
  spawn(/^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm', ['-v'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
  ```
- for node.js 5.x and later:

  ```
  spawn('npm', ['-v'], {stdio: 'inherit', shell: true})
  ```

Comment: Where to do these modifications?

Comment: Key part is adding `shell: true`

Answer (score 22):

For anyone who might stumble upon this, if all the other answers do not help and you are on Windows, know that there is currently [a big issue with `spawn` on Windows](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2318) and the `PATHEXT` environment variable that can cause certain calls to spawn to not work depending on how the target command is installed.

Comment: And what's the solution?

Comment: Using node-cross-spawn worked for me. See answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35561971/507339

Comment: Spent ages trying to find what was wrong and this ended up being the problem. I gave up on `spawn` and just used `exec` instead.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I was getting this error thrown due to the necessary dependent system resources not being installed.

More specifically, I have a NodeJS app that is utilizing ImageMagick.  Despite having the npm package installed, the core Linux ImageMagick was not installed.  I did an apt-get to install ImageMagick and after that all worked great!

Comment: Does windows need ImageMagick installed as well? Im testing on windows and getting error

Comment: Running `yarn` (To install) fixed it

Comment: Simply run `brew install imagemagick`

Answer (score 11):

Before anyone spends to much time debugging this problem, most of the time it can be resolved by deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling the packages.

#### To Install:

If a lockfile exists you might use

```
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
```

or

```
npm ci
```

respectivly. if not then

```
yarn install
```

or

```
npm i
```

Comment: Wow such a simple solution and it worked for me! Everyone should try this first to see if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 6):

### Are you changing the `env` option?

Then look at this answer.

---

I was trying to spawn a node process and TIL that you should spread the existing environment variables when you spawn else you'll loose the `PATH` environment variable and possibly other important ones.

This was the fix for me:

```js
const nodeProcess = spawn('node', ['--help'], {
  env: {
    // by default, spawn uses `process.env` for the value of `env`
    // you can _add_ to this behavior, by spreading `process.env`
    ...process.env,
    OTHER_ENV_VARIABLE: 'test',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you're experiencing this issue with an application whose source you cannot modify consider invoking it with the environment variable `NODE_DEBUG` set to `child_process`, e.g. `NODE_DEBUG=child_process yarn test`. This will provide you with information which command lines have been invoked in which directory and usually the last detail is the reason for the failure.

Comment: do you know the minimum node --version to be able to use this technique?

Comment: @laconbass No. I think that's a good SO question which will be anwered within hours.

Comment: Just got curious. It's way better and cleaner than answer I've checked as accepted

Answer (score 3):

I had this appear while building `gulp-jekyll` in `Powershell` on `Windows 11`.

`nodejs 10 LTS`, `gulp v3.9.1`, `ruby 3.1`, `bundler 2.4.5`, `jekyll 4.2.2`

This line of code here is the cause of the `ENOENT` issue I had with `spawn` and `bundle`.

```js
  return cp.spawn('bundle', [
    'exec', 
    'jekyll', 
    'build', 
    '--source=app', '--destination=build/development', '--config=_config.yml', '--profile'
  ], { stdio: 'inherit' })
  .on('close', done);
```

Two errors returned, and troubleshooting should start here.

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn bundle ENOENT
```

The `cp.spawn` is not handling an error Event, so handling that with a simple `console.log()` will expose the real error with debug information:

```js
  return cp.spawn('bundle', [
    'exec', 
    'jekyll', 
    'build', 
    '--source=app', '--destination=build/development', '--config=_config.yml', '--profile'
  ], { stdio: 'inherit' })
  .on('error', (e) => console.log(e))
  .on('close', done);
```

This now provides a lot more information to debug with.

```
{ Error: spawn bundle ENOENT
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn bundle',
  path: 'bundle',
  spawnargs:
   [ 'exec',
     'jekyll',
     'build',
     '--source=app',
     '--destination=build/development',
     '--config=_config.yml',
     '--profile' ] }
```

The next step to debug would be using the `nodejs 10 LTS` documentation for [`child_process.spawn(command[, args][, options])`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options). As already described above, adding the `{ shell: true }` to the options of spawn is a working solution. This is what solved my problem as well.

```js
  { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true }
```

This solution is merely a band-aid and could be refactored to handle all environments, but that is out of scope for how to troubleshoot & debug the `spawn ENOENT` error on `nodejs`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, but I found a simple way to fix it.
It appears to be `spawn()` errors if the program has been added to the PATH by the user (e.g. normal system commands work).

To fix this, you can use the [which](https://www.npmjs.com/package/which) module (`npm install --save which`):

```
// Require which and child_process
const which = require('which');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
// Find npm in PATH
const npm = which.sync('npm');
// Execute
const noErrorSpawn = spawn(npm, ['install']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `require('child_process').exec` instead of spawn for a more specific error message!

for example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var commandStr = 'java -jar something.jar';

exec(commandStr, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if(error || stderr) console.log(error || stderr);
  else console.log(stdout);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A case that I found that is not in this list but it's worthy to be added:

On Alpine Linux, Node will error with ENOENT if the executable is not compatible.

Alpine expects binaries with `libc`. An executable (e.g. `chrome` as part of chromium) that has been compiled with `glibc` as a wrapper for system calls, will fail with ENOENT when called by `spawn`.

Comment: yes this is the issue. In order to fix this follow this
https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3649#issuecomment-447115855

Answer (score 1):

Ensure module to be executed is installed or full path to command if it's not a node module

Answer (score 1):

I was also going through this annoying problem while running my test cases, so I tried many ways to get across it. But the way works for me is to **run your test runner from the directory which contains your main file** which includes your **nodejs spawn** function something like this:

```
nodeProcess = spawn('node',params, {cwd: '../../node/', detached: true });
```

For example, this **file name is test.js**, so just **move to the folder which contains it**. In my case, it is test folder like this:

```
cd root/test/
```

then from **run your test runner** in my case its mocha so it will be like this:

```
mocha test.js
```

I have wasted my more than one day to figure it out. Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

solution in my case

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const isWindows = /^win/.test(process.platform); 

spawn(isWindows ? 'twitter-proxy.cmd' : 'twitter-proxy');
spawn(isWindows ? 'http-server.cmd' : 'http-server');
```

Comment: While this may be a solution for win specific fixes, I don't see how it helps to debug the real cause of the ENOENT

Comment: I have no idea why, but the spawn call would work in the node repl without the `.cmd`, but fail in a typescript jest test. -- This error can be quite hard to figure out, this answers deserves more upvotes.

Comment: The `.cmd` extension thing is already covered by existing answers

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on Windows, where calling `exec` and `spawn` with the exact same command (omitting arguments) worked fine for `exec` (so I knew my command was on `$PATH`), but `spawn` would give ENOENT. Turned out that I just needed to append `.exe` to the command I was using:

```
import { exec, spawn } from 'child_process';

// This works fine
exec('p4 changes -s submitted');

// This gives the ENOENT error
spawn('p4');

// But this resolves it
spawn('p4.exe');
// Even works with the arguments now
spawn('p4.exe', ['changes', '-s', 'submitted']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when trying to debug a node.js program from within VS Code editor on a Debian Linux system. I noticed the same thing worked OK on Windows. The solutions previously given here weren't much help because I hadn't written any "spawn" commands. The offending code was presumably written by Microsoft and hidden under the hood of the VS Code program.

Next I noticed that node.js is called node on Windows but on Debian (and presumably on Debian-based systems such as Ubuntu) it's called nodejs. So I created an alias - from a root terminal, I ran

ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node

and this solved the problem. The same or a similar procedure will presumably work in other cases where your node.js is called nodejs but you're running a program which expects it to be called node, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows Node.js does some funny business when handling quotes that may result in you issuing a command that you know works from the console, but does not when run in Node. For example the following *should* work:

```
spawn('ping', ['"8.8.8.8"'], {});
```

but fails. There's a fantastically undocumented option `windowsVerbatimArguments` for handling quotes/similar that seems to do the trick, just be sure to add the following to your opts object:

```
const opts = {
    windowsVerbatimArguments: true
};
```

and your command should be back in business.

```
 spawn('ping', ['"8.8.8.8"'], { windowsVerbatimArguments: true });
```

Comment: Don't quote the arguments inside the array

Comment: @laconbass This is an obviously trivial example to convey the concept and so the quotes could be removed. However, there are cases where you absolutely need to quote the arguments (for example if you need to pass an argument that has a path with a space in it: _"C:\Program Files\..."_). I posted it here because, even though it may not have been the cause of your specific error case, it will hopefully help someone else experiencing this cryptic error because of Node's handling of quotes on Windows like I was encountering.

Comment: node.js already makes some Black Magic and silently quotes arguments "properly". Your example should work without the undocumented option you mention, by unquoting argument inside the array.

Comment: Just to add my own experience, I was running a java process from node. This error happened to me because of quotes around the command, rather than the argument. Test with spaces in the command path and it still works without quotes

Answer (score 0):

Although it may be an environment path or another issue for some people, I had just installed the Latex Workshop extension for Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 and saw this error when attempting to build/preview the PDF. Running VS Code as Administrator solved the problem for me.

Comment: Again, related do filesystem path some way. The extension probably can't reach a path without admin permissions

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing node, delete all AppData/Roaming/npm and AppData/Roaming/npm-cache and installing node once again solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also faced similar issue.

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn null ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

It was due to having a wrong configuration in `.env` file for `BROWSER`. I had `BROWSER=null`, but it has to be `BROWSER=none`. Changing that configuration resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all nothing worked , my system has different issue .

The working solution for me is
**run command** :
npm config set script-shell "C:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe"

Comment: Your issue seems more related to `npm` itself rather than to node's `child_process.spawn()`. And seems like a windows quirk

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error for windows 8.The issue is because of an environment variable of your system path is missing . Add "C:\Windows\System32\" value to your system  PATH variable.

Answer (score -1):

#### Local development on Emulator

Make sure to have the package installed locally. By changing the `spawn` command with `exec` i got a more detailed error and found out I didn't install the package. Simply run, to check if the package is present:

`brew install imagemagick`

[Source](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/502#issuecomment-510031410)

Answer (score -3):

Add `C:\Windows\System32\` to the `path` environment variable.

### Steps

1. Go to my *computer and properties*
2. Click on *Advanced settings*
3. Then on *Environment variables*
4. Select `Path` and then click on edit
5. Paste the following if not already present: `C:\Windows\System32\`
6. Close the command prompt
7. Run the command that you wanted to run

[image: Windows 8 Environment variables screenshot]

Comment: This is a duplicate of [chayasan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37071607/1218980)

Answer (score -4):

For me I made following changes in package.json.

```
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --open",    // delete this line
    "dev": "vite",           // with this one
   .....
  }
```