# Pulling files from a directory into the root folder for NPM

Tags: npm

I am publishing a library to NPM.

When I build the library, the resulting artifact is placed in the `dist` folder located in the root of my project as `index.js`.

When users install from NPM I would like `index.js` to be present in the *root* of the folder created in their `node_modules` folder. Presently, it remains in a directory named `dist`.

How can I do this?

My packages.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "files": ["dist/*"],
  "main": "index.min.js",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": "git@github.com:username/my-package.git"
}
```

Comment: Place the resulting artifact at the root instead? Or, use a `prepublish` script to copy the artifact to root then remove it `postpublish`? Or, use a `postinstall` script to move the file to the root?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem.

I solved it not by copying the files up, but by copying the files I needed down into the `./dist/` folder and then doing an `npm publish` from there; NPM then treats that folder as a complete package and everything works very nicely.  The only files I needed to copy from the root folder were:

- `package.json`
- `README.md`

Because we're going to copy these files down into the `./dist/` folder before we do the publish, we do NOT want the `package.json` file to reference `./dist/`.   So remove the `package.json`'s `files` entry completely, because we don't need to tell it which files we'll take - we're going to take everything in the `./dist/` folder.  I'm using TypeScript so I also have a `typings` entry, and again no reference to `./dist/`.

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "0.0.9",
  "main": "index.min.js",
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": "git@github.com:username/my-package.git"
}
```

Now for the publish step.  I built a gulp task that will perform the publish for me, making it nice and automated (except for incrementing the package version #).

From gulp I'll use Node's spawn() to kick-off the npm process.  However, because I'm actually working on Windows I used "[cross-spawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn)" rather than the normal built-in Node.js spawn (which I learned the hard way didn't work when I had spaces in my path!).

Here's my gulp file, with the TypeScript bits removed:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');
var spawn =  require('cross-spawn'); // WAS: require('child_process').spawn;

var config = {
    src: { tsFiles: './src/**/*.ts' },
    out: { path: './dist/' }
}

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return del('dist/*');
});


gulp.task('build', ['clean'], () => {
    ....
});


gulp.task('publish', ['build'], (done) => {
    // Copy the files we'll need to publish
    // We just use built-in gulp commands to do the copy
    gulp.src(['package.json', 'README.md']).pipe(gulp.dest(config.out.path));

    // We'll start the npm process in the dist directory
    var outPath = config.out.path.replace(/(\.)|(\/)/gm,'');
    var distDir = __dirname + '\\' + outPath + '\\';
    console.log("dist directory = " + distDir);

    // Start the npm process
    spawn('npm', ['publish'], { stdio:'inherit', cwd:distDir } )
        .on('close', done)
        .on('error', function(error) {
            console.error('  Underlying spawn error: ' + error);
            throw error;
        });
});
```

Notice when we call spawn() we pass in a 3rd argument which is the options.  The main entry here is the `cwd:distDir`, which tells spawn to run the npm process from the ./dist/ directory.   Because using spawn can cause problems I've hooked into the spawn error handling.   As I was troubleshooting my use of `spawn()` I found the following [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js) article very helpful.

This worked like a charm; my published package has all the files in the root directory and the `./dist/` folder is not published.