# How do you specify the require/import base path?

Tags: javascript, npm

In my **package.json** file I have the `main` option where I specify the default include for when you `import 'my-index' from 'my-module'`

However I want to split `my-module` into separate files, and let the developer include them individually: `import 'my-index/another-file from 'my-module'`.

I see one option is to put `another-file.js` in the root of the `my-module` repository, but I don't want to place that in the root, I want it in **src/another-file.js**.

Is there a way to specify this in the **package.json** file?

Comment: See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3953

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently do this, instead use either the `prepublish` and `postpublish` hooks in the **package.json** file, or use the `postinstall` hook. With these you can move the files to the root of your project:

**See:** [Pulling files from a directory into the root folder for NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29438400/pulling-files-from-a-directory-into-the-root-folder-for-npm)

```
{
    "prepublish": "mv dist/* . && rm -rf dist",
    "postpublish": "rm keo.js redux.js middleware.js"
}
```

Also **do not** forget to update the `files` array in the **package.json** to reflect the new location of the files, otherwise they won't be included when a developer issues `npm i`.