# Accessing SVN using nodeJs and "svn-spawn" module

Tags: node.js, svn

I am new to nodeJS and I am trying to access SVN using the package [svn-spawn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svn-spawn). My code is given below.

```
var Client = require('svn-spawn');
var client = new Client({
    cwd: 'C:\\SVN\\Source Code',
    username: 'abcd', 
    password: 'xyz', 
});
client.getInfo(function(err, data) {
console.log('Repository url is %s', data.url);
});
```

But I am getting the following error on execution:

```
console.log('Repository url is %s', data.url);
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
at C:\NodeJS\SvnTest.js:9:45
```

"data" is undefined.

Comment: Try to console.log(err); and console.log(data);

Comment: On console.log(data) is gives "undefined".
On console.log(err), i got the following.
{ [Error: spawn svn ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn svn',
  path: 'svn' }

Comment: Probably it's because of space in path, try to move to dir without it. Error tells that there is no such folder.

Comment: I tried to do that as well. I am still getting the same error. :(

Comment: Another clue that you don't have svn.exe in your %PATH% variable. Try to read this article how to debug this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the svn-command tool? It seems the module require you to install svn-command locally, I got the same error and fixed once I install the svn-command tool...