# Fatal error: spawn cmd ENOENT - Grunt Serve

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

When i run grunt serve i get this.

```
Running "browserSync:livereload" (browserSync) task
    [BS] Access URLs:
     ------------------------------------
           Local: http://localhost:9000
        External: http://192.168.1.5:9000
     ------------------------------------
              UI: http://localhost:3001
     UI External: http://192.168.1.5:3001
     ------------------------------------
    [BS] Serving files from: .tmp
    [BS] Serving files from: app
    [BS] Watching files...
    Fatal error: spawn cmd ENOENT
```

Hello Stackoverflow! I have been trying get the yeoman-angular server running. I have got the server running before but now i keep getting this error.

I believe the major problem here is Spawn cmd ENOENT. I have googled the error but i still have no idea what to do. It seems my Path environment is messed up. Please help!

Comment: This could possibly help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/27688805/736967

Comment: Check if the same port is used by another program

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same error running grunt serve on a 64-bit Windows 7 system.  I've never experienced this problem on my Macbook Air.  What worked for me was right-clicking and opening the Command Prompt using "Run as Administrator." I was then able to navigate to my project directory and run grunt serve without errors.  I noticed that this modified my system path, so I agree that this is probably a path-related issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However StackOverflow is a very busy site and has therefore strict guidelines for quality answers. Perhaps some people will find your answer somewhat chatty and vague. Please don't take this the wrong way. Others will tell you very directly or even downvote you. You might find it quite harsh, but this is StackOverflow.

Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running browserSync on Windows 7 64-bit.

Just in case if anyone stumbles across the same problem, I had to add `%SystemRoot%\system32` to `PATH` environment variable and it solved the issue. `%SystemRoot%` usually resolves to `C:\Windows\system32` (and it contains `cmd.exe`).

I remembered this solution from one of the issues in GitHub browser-sync repo. I will update the answer with the issue link, if I find it.