# Angular - Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: angularjs

**Hi I have problem when I generate angular - yo angular.**

I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.

invoke       angular:route
   invoke           angular:controller:C:\Users\david\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-angular\route\index.js
   create             app\scripts\controllers\about.js
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Anyone show me how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: what OS are you trying to do this on, and what version of NPM are you using? you haven't provided enough detail for anyone to provide a useful answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)

Comment: Hi, I'm using window 7 home edition  - 64 bit OS - Cmder terminal  - > npm -v 2.14.3 -> bower -v 1.5.2

Comment: Hi I unable to find the solution from How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js

Answer (score 8):

Im not sure why this error comes about, however i managed to run my Angular application by running with  : **ng serve** instead of **ng serve --open** . Please not you will need to copy the url manually and place it in the browser afterwards which should be **http://localhost:4200/**

Comment: Thanks Daniel ... This worked for me ... Although I would like to know is it possible now in the current version of angular to run `ng serve --open`

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue for windows 8 and tried several installations after doing changes to AppData/Roaming folder. None of the solutions worked for me. The issue is because of an environment variable of your system path is missing . Add "C:\Windows\System32\" value to your system  PATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

this error occurs when your terminal is not having access to open browers or admin permision try running your terminal as admin

Answer (score 1):

I've got this issue after updating Angular CLI to 11.0.2 and I've been spent a lot of time to resolve this,

Apparently, I've tried the default port to serve my project and it served without any errors. which is  `http://localhost:4200/` but, I needed to run on  `http://localhost:8000/` So I did this....

First of all try remove node_modules from your directory and re-install npm packages. (I'm saying this because, some users got resolved the issue) to re-install npm packages, run

```
npm i
```

or run below command

```
npm install
```

if this didn't work, try adding the port number to the `angular.json` file.

search for serve options in the `json` file.

[image]

then add your desired port number like this `"port": 8000,`
(P.S. 'WorkspaceUI' means my project name and I've been trying to run on '8000' port. you can run on your own port number.) Then run your project using `ng serve` command. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many guesses on different portal for this error and none of them works. Here is the solution -
Run this command to install angular cli before performing anything -

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```