# How to catch an ENOENT with nodejs child_process.fork?

Tags: node.js, child-process

This is what I am doing:

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var child = fork('some_script');
  child.on('error', function(err) {
         console.log(err);
});
```

I want to catch the error if the script is not valid.
There is an answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208614/how-to-catch-an-enoent-with-nodejs-child-process-spawn) which works great for *spawn* but fails for *fork*. There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js) answer which helps to debug but does not serve my purpose. I want to log the error as the script is dynamically generated.

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (exception) { ...}
```

is neither recommended nor will work, I think...

**UPDATE: Yes, it is a duplicate. Sorry I missed it. However, I am repeating the comment of RobertKlep here. Now the code is 1 instead of 8 in the cited answer. Thats important to note.**

Comment: I have to add that recent versions of Node exit with code 1 instead of 8 as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @robertklep  Thanks. It is indeed a duplicate. I did not find it in my search for whatever reason. Yes, 1 and not 8 works now.

Comment: @robertklep Anyway I can find out the other codes? I do not see it in the docs.

Comment: [See here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_exit_codes) for a list of error codes for the most recent Node versions.