# Error: spawn npm ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I have an JS app. It works good on linux but in windows 10 I am getting an error.

```
events.js:161
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1028:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:422:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:143:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:537:3
```

and the code which is incorrect is this

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const watching = [
  // {service: "babel-watch"},
  {service: "webpack-watch"},
  // {service: "sass-watch"},
  {service: "server-watch"}
];

watching.forEach(({service}) => {
  const child = spawn('npm', ['run', service]);
  child.stdout.on('data', d => console.log(d.toString()));
  child.stderr.on('data', d => console.log(d.toString()));
});
```

I found the reason of this error in [github](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5841) I guess the problem is spawn [nodejs spawn Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) which have didn't work correctly in windows. But I don't know how to modify this snippet of code to make it work. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Try suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208614/how-to-catch-an-enoent-with-nodejs-child-process-spawn to get more info about the error

Comment: Which NodeJS version your are using it?

Comment: @PramodPatil v7.6.0

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Just changed this line

```
const child = spawn('npm', ['run', service]);
```

to this line

```
  const child = spawn(/^win/.test(process.platform) ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm', ['run',  service]);
```

Which is checking the operating system if ti's windows it runs npm.cmd if it's linux just npm

Comment: where exactly do u go and add this line? event.js file?

Comment: Strange, since I can call npm by itself normally on command, but this was most certainly solved my issue as well. Lifesaver.

Comment: Also solved the problem for me using npx.

Comment: search in the entire project for `spawn('` and replace as it was suggested in this answer

Answer (score 7):

I know there is a correct answer and this question has been around for a long time, my solution is based on the answer @Armen Sanoyan and [How do I determine the current operating system with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683895/how-do-i-determine-the-current-operating-system-with-node-js)

For me the @Armen Sanoyan answer does not work, but help a lot. I changed for this line and work.

```
const child = (process.platform === 'win32' ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm') + ' run ' + service;
```

I hope I can help.

Answer (score 3):

I know this seems obvious but make sure you're not putting several flags/options into a single string:

```
// do not do this
spawn('pnpm', ['-r', 'exec', '--', 'pnpm version patch'])

// do this
spawn('pnpm', ['-r', 'exec', '--', 'pnpm', 'version', 'patch'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. My application code was running fine in MAC but in Windows it was giving an error about the code related to the spawn command

The error occurs when running using `command prompt`

When I used `GIT bash` to start the application then the error did not occur. I did not need to change any code

Comment: I had to also delete the favicon.ico file from code repository because I was unable to start the application due to some error when this file is present in my local windows machine