# How to catch ENOENT error when spawning a child process in node.js on Windows, without using "shell: true"

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to create a child process, using spawn, and would like to be able to handle if the "cwd" is not found. When it's not found, it throws an "ENOENT" error, which on Windows I can only seem to catch if I spawn the process with the "shell: true" property. So what I'm doing:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const childProcess = spawn('MyCommand.exe', [], {
    cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'mypath')
}

childProcess.on('error', (err) => {
    // Handle error here
})

childProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
    // Handle exit event
})
```

On Windows, the above will not properly catch the ENOENT exception unless I do:

```
const childProcess = spawn('MyCommand.exe', [], {
    cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'mypath'),
    shell: true
}
```

If I spawn using the above then, if the cwd or command isn't found, the `exit` event will catch the exception.

But I'd really like to be able to do it without running it in a shell. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: sorryi dont have the answer but you gave me the aswer about ENOENT error catching. Thank you!! You should post it it to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208614/how-to-catch-an-enoent-with-nodejs-child-process-spawn)