# visual studio code nodejs request 'launch': cannot launch target (reason: spawn node ENOENT)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

When I use visual studio code to debug a nodejs app.
visual studio code tell me `request 'launch': cannot launch target (reason: spawn node ENOENT)`

[image]

My nodejs version is 4.2.4

Comment: is it happen after install, then restart visual studio code

Answer (score 3):

Managed to get past this when running on Windows by specifying `npm.cmd` instead of `npm` in the VS code debug configuration like so

```
"runtimeExecutable": "npm.cmd",
```

Answer (score 2):

Some discussions are posted in this here

[How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)

Especially, the following points should be checked

- Ensure the environment variable `PATH` is set
- `PATHEXT` environment variable that can cause certain calls to spawn to not work on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error on a Debian Linux system. I noticed the same thing worked OK on Windows.

Next I noticed that the Node.JS executable is called node on Windows but on Debian (and on Debian-based systems such as Ubuntu) it's called nodejs. So I created an alias - from a root terminal, I ran

ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/bin/node

and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you already had your Visual Code Editor running while installing node js on Windows OS. I would advise you to shut down your Visual Studio Code and restart it. This problem should go away.

If not do a machine reboot and verify if the debug works flawlessly