# Error: spawn java ENOENT only in my environment

Tags: java, node.js, mean-stack

I have a MEAN Project that calls a `.jar` file to process an algorithm. In other machines the system all works fine but in my environment when I execute the method that connects with the `.jar`, I got this error:

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1057:32)
    at child_process.js:1151:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I read the QAs related in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js) but all the answers tell me to do something in the code, but I think the problem is not in the code because in my coworkers notebooks this works great.

Does anybody have some idea of how to solve this problem? I tried to run (again) `npm install` but all the packages are successfully installed.