# Rust (VSCode) Error: spawnSync undefined ENOENT

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error:

> Error: spawnSync undefined ENOENT

Always, when I save the file in VSCode, but it turns out that compiles fine.

How I can fix this behavior?

I read this:
[How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)
but I do not know if this related.

Comment: This is VS Code trying to spawn a new process. Have you installed any Rust plugins? If so, which ones?

Comment: @JeremiahPeschka ...spawn a new process ? It happens when I save the file. ....Rust plugins? yes Rust-Code and vsc-rustfmt

Comment: @JeremiahPeschka please promote your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this by uninstalling the extra plugin **rust_fmt** besides **rusty_code** because of which vscode spawning new process every time on save. Also enabled fmt from vscode settings as below.

```
 "rust.formatOnSave": true,
 "rust.checkOnSave": true
```