# How to trigger node filename.js file in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, child-process

I'm trying to trigger one JS file from Electron. If I try the command node test.js in the terminal, it's working fine. If I try the same thing in Electron, I'm getting an error `Uncaught Error: spawn node test.js ENOENT`. Can you correct me if I'm on the wrong path?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var executeSpawn = spawn('node test.js',{
    cwd: process.resourcesPath+'/app/test.js'});

executeSpawn.stdout.on('data',function(data){
    console.log(`data:${data}`);
});

executeSpawn.stderr.on('data',function(data){
    console.log("data:",data);
});

executeSpawn.on('close',function(ev){
    console.log("ev",ev);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js) containing several good methods to try and debug this error type.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely late to the party, but node's `fork` exists exactly for the purpose of running an external node file.

parent.js

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const forked = fork('child.js');

forked.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from child', msg);
});

forked.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

child.js

```
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from parent:', msg);
});

let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  process.send({ counter: counter++ });
}, 1000);
```

Example shamelessly taken from [this freecodecamp tutorial on Node.js child processes](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a).

P.S.: The linked SO post in the first answer has more information on the `ENOENT` error concerning `spawn`.