# /bin/sh not found -- spawnSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

after executing a command with `execSync` which executes with `sh` I noticed the following:

`spawnSync /bin/sh ENOENT`

`bin` is currently added to PATH.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally the cause is that the path where you are executing this doesn't exist

see the accepted answer in this question

[How do I debug “Error: spawn ENOENT” on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)

Comment: hmm...so if I execute `/bin/sh` in console it does find the folder

Comment: is not that the /bin/sh is not there is that the folder where are you running the command not exist like if you do: exec('pwd', {  cwd:'/home/user/directory'}; will fail with the error if the cwd path not exist

Comment: hmm would it not error out saying the cwd does exist as opposed to bin/sh?

Comment: this is the problem, node not say that the cwd not exists just say that [Error: spawn /bin/sh ENOENT]

Answer (score 7):

This error can also be caused by passing a directory that does not exist to the `cwd`. Double check that the path you are passing as the `cwd` option is correct.

Comment: wow! that was exactly my case! I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what was the issue, but didn't event think that I made a typo in cwd parameter for PM2 ecosystem file. Thanks!