# I cant find restart button in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, button, restart

When i open Visual Studio i see on the top buttons: File, Edit, Selection, View, Go, Debug, Taks and Help. Whatever button i opened i couldnt find any restart button. I searched on the google and also on this website what should i do. I got few same answers- that i should download some sort of **restart extension** (i am new in programming, so im not quite sure what is the name of it). When i dowloaded it and inserted it in Visual Studio, there was this sentence thats says that VS wont open the file because its **too large** ( i think that there were another 2 reasons ). I googled that and still couldnt find anything helpful. In all of this searching i found out that this is might connected to option tools
 and customize
 but i cannot find them aswell. Can anyone tell me roughly what might be the problem? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for some way to restart visual studio, say after installing some plugins, all you need to do is Close and Re-Open it. There is no specific restart button

Comment: Okay, i tried this way few times, but nothing has happened. Here is the link of my exact problem, maybe i am making mistake somowhere else. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949845/visual-studio-python-failed-to-launch-the-python-process-please-validate-the-p
I tried to do this many times, and nothing is working when i just re-open, so i was thinking that there  maybe is some restart button. When i searched it on google it looked like there really is, but that i dont have it..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/7317256 shows an easier to follow guide on what that answer is trying to get you to do

Comment: Thank you very much, i will check it few times.