# Debug console doesnt show any output

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im starting a python basic course and trying to run some initial code with Vscode. After watching the course videos i notice that im not seeing any output under the DEBUG CONSOLE. I do get an output under the TERMINAL section.
Also, i notice that the debug icon is different compared to the one in the videos (mine has a play arrow).

Am i missing something?

My python

```
C:\Users\andres>py --version
Python 3.8.3
```

my current launch.json is

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
         
    }
]
```

}

thanks

[image]

Comment: you need to add `"console": "internalConsole",`  instead [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345409/vs-code-shows-print-output-in-terminal-instead-of-output/62350835#62350835)

Comment: Thanks. Now got a new error: "Failed to spawn laucher" "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Comment: can you check some of the answers here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949845/visual-studio-python-failed-to-launch-the-python-process-please-validate-the-p

Comment: none of them work. i still get WinError 123 when i run a python file at VSCode

Comment: can you add some screenshots of all the errors and where they are occurring to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @tHeSiD for the initial advise. for the winerror123, i deleted and recreated the json file