# Error executing Firefox CasperJS/SlimerJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, casperjs, slimerjs

I'm trying to make some tests written with CasperJS run using SlimerJS, but I'm getting the follow error:

[image: Error executing firefox]

I've downloaded SlimerJS by using `npm install slimerjs` at my project's folder, and I did configure a system variable `SLIMERJSLAUNCHER` pointing to where my `firefox.exe` is in, as described on SlimerJS's website.

Here is the whole structure:

[image: Project structure]

SlimerJS folder is into `node_modules`.

I'm trying to run these tests on my command prompt using `npm test` which is:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "casperjs --engine=slimerjs test test.js"
  },
```

Versions:

- CasperJS 1.1.3
- SlimerJS 0.10.2
- Firefox 50.0.2

I can really can use any help here. Thanks.

Comment: You need to fix the `Error: spawn ENOENT` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js/27688805#27883443).

Comment: Hi, @gustavo-arcega, did you manage to fix this problem?