# ng-cli error in Node js 7.x

Tags: node.js, npm, angular2-cli

I am using Windows 10. 
I installed nodejs 7.4.0 using windows installer.
I installed typescript globally.
I installed ng-cli globally.
Then I went to command prompt into my new project folder and did "ng init".
It throws the following error.

```
events.js:154
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn sh ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:182:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:348:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:449:11)
    at startup (node.js:148:18)
    at node.js:405:3
```

Any advise please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js potentially helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I should have installed "angular-cli" instead of "ng-cli".
This fixed my issue.