# mockserver-grunt Error spawn java ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, mockserver

I am trying to start a mockserver-grunt using node modules. My problem is that the following error occurs:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

 Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
 (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:609:11)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

I know there a lot of questions here about this error, but I've tried a lot of answers and none of it worked. This is the first time I'm working with node and mockserver.
For example I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883443/1214049)

And my output is:

```
{ '0': 'java',
  '1': 
    [ '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8',
    '-Dmockserver.logLevel=WARN',
    '-jar',
    [ 'mockserver-netty-3.10.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar' ],
    '-serverPort',
    5000 ],
  '2': { stdio: [ 'ignore', 'ignore', [Object] ] } }
```

My mock_server.js looks like this:

`var mockserver = require('mockserver-grunt');
mockserver.start_mockserver({serverPort: 5000});`

and I checked, there are no other programs running on port 5000.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "test",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "## Required environment vars",
 "main": "mock_server.js",
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "bower": "^1.7.9",
   "grunt": "1.0.1",
   "grunt-cli": "1.2.0",
   "mockserver-grunt": "^1.0.41"
}
```

I have also installed a project from scratch and the same thing happens. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is how I resolved this issue.
I tried to run locally:

```
java -Dmockserver.logLevel=INFO -jar ~/Downloads/mockserver-netty-3.10.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar -serverPort -5000
```

And it seemed like:

```
bash: java: command not found
```

After I installed java, I started the server
    `node mock_server.js` and all went good.

So yeah, I knew this was a silly problem...