# Launch ares-launch ERR! uncaughtException Error: spawn cmd ENOENT

Tags: javascript, web, spawn, webos

i am developing a web application in WebOS platform. as i am able to install the application on TV but i am unable to debug it. i am getting the below statements in console.

here is my console:

```
9/12/17, 3:09:58 PM : [Package] Creating package com.yourdomain.app_0.0.1_all.ipk in C:\Users\Apalya\Desktop\ramkoti backup\Jai workspace\webappsample_html5videoplayer\OutputIPK\webappsample_html5videoplayer_TV
9/12/17, 3:09:58 PM : [Package] Success
9/12/17, 3:10:00 PM : [Install] Installing package C:\Users\Apalya\Desktop\ramkoti backup\Jai workspace\webappsample_html5videoplayer\OutputIPK\webappsample_html5videoplayer_TV\com.yourdomain.app_0.0.1_all.ipk
9/12/17, 3:10:05 PM : [Install] Success
9/12/17, 3:10:07 PM : [Launch] Launched application com.yourdomain.app
9/12/17, 3:10:10 PM : [Launch] Application Debugging - http://localhost:49313/devtools/devtools.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:49313/devtools/page/CB7C27BB-7485-F5D9-189D-A1D256D9CA38
9/12/17, 3:10:10 PM: [Launch] ares-launch ERR! uncaughtException Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
9/12/17, 3:10:10 PM : [Launch] Caught exception: Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
```

Please help me, i am unable to track why i am getting exception while debugging, actually i was working on this project and it works fine upto last 2 days, i think the problem is not with code bcoz all sample application were un-able to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Put the wrapper function, at the top of the index.js or whatever your server's starting script.

Comment: Hi GABBAR, Thanks for your quick response, i have used wrapper function too(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js). but no use.

Answer (score 0):

exec() will tell you what command it tried to run.
so u can just change spawn() to exec() and try again.

Comment: Hi Gabbar, i am not using spawn() in my project.