# Error occurs on doing npm start

Tags: npm

I downloaded quickseed application from angular.io but when i do npm install and try to run application using npm start it shows the error

```
Error occured when executing command: npm run serve
 Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:32)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:376:16)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
     at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
     at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
 Error occured when executing command: npm run serve
 Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:32)
     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:376:16)
     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
     at Module.runMain (module.js:606:11)
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
     at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
[1] npm run serve exited with code -4058
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-io-example@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-io-example@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dhruv\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-10-23T17_48_44_893Z-debug.log

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

`ENOENT` is a C `errno` value meaning "does not exist". 
However, it seems you're in luck: other people have create this [Stackoverflow question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js).