# how to fix the unhandled error while executing the angular application

Tags: angular

When I tried to execute the angular application. Iam getting an error as Un handled error event like below .is it path problem? or is it because of version problem?

```
error: spawn cmd enoent at process.childprocess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19) at onerrornt (internal/child_process.js:415:16) at process._tickcallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) emitted 'error' event at: at process.childprocess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12) at onerrornt (internal/child_process.js:415:16) at process._tickcallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63)
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information with your problem. I meant the steps you went through to reproduce the error

Comment: See if this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27688804/1850609

Comment: actually when i tried to execute the applications in angular it shows the above error.so i thought it will be a path problem so i changed that but still the error came, then uninstalled the nodejs and reinstalled  .after that installed the npm commands.once it was done .i tried a simple example in angular and tried to execute it.while executing the same error occurs .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method i tried is uninstalled the all dependencies , Nodejs and angular and also i cleared the cache .Once again i reinstalled everything , difference in versions also causes problems sometime, so need to consider that also.I made sure the correct versions are installed .that Works.