# How to fix "Error: spawn py ENOENT" error when running python script from electron app?

Tags: javascript, python, npm, electron

I was trying to run some python script from electron app in windows 10.The sample code that I am trying to run is:

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
PythonShell.run('test.py',  function  (err, results)  {
 if  (err)  throw err;
 console.log('test.py finished.');
 console.log('results', results);
});
```

The code is expected to run test.py which contains a simple print statement.But the terminal shows the following  error log:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn py ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

> Looks like the Python executable is not available from your node
>   script, which is almost always the case in Windows. Either add the
>   python executable to your PATH variable, or specify the executable
>   path in the options. See constructor options for more details.

Use https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell#pythonshellscript-options-constructor

Set pythonPath & try.

```
let options = {
    pythonPath: 'C:\\python27\\python',
  };

  let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
  PythonShell.run('test.py', options,  function  (err, results)  {
   if  (err)  throw err;
   console.log('test.py finished.');
   console.log('results', results);
  });
```

https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/issues/3#issuecomment-52174564

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated my path variable and also included the path to python executable in options. But this error is still there..

Comment: @IftekharJamil What do you have in 'test.py'?

Comment: It contains just a print statement: `import sys
print("Hello world")`

Answer (score 0):

For Mac

1. install python 2.7 from python site.
2. copy the directory “/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python”
3. open node modules and 'dmg builder' folder and 'dmg.js' file replace “/usr/bin/python”.

still same error --->

1. upgrade the electron build
   "yarn add electron-builder --dev"

I used child process, I'm not sure this will work on python-shell

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).