# Is there any due process for running react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Please does anyone have a solution to this?

- Node version--12
- npm version--6.13.4

When I type `npm start` it gives this error:

> ```
> C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Reaactapps>cd react_1
>
> C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Reaactapps\react_1>npm start
>
> react_1@0.1.0 start C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Reaactapps\react_1
> react-scripts start
>
> Starting the development server...
>
> events.js:288
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
> Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
> ←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)←[39m
> ←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)←[39m
> ←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m
> Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
> ←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)←[39m
> ←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)←[39m
> ←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m {
>   errno: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
>   code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
>   syscall: ←[32m'spawn cmd'←[39m,
>   path: ←[32m'cmd'←[39m,
>   spawnargs: [ ←[32m'/s'←[39m, ←[32m'/c'←[39m, ←[32m'start'←[39m, ←[32m'""'←[39m, ←[32m'/b'←[39m, ←[32m'"http://localhost:3000"'←[39m ]
> }
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! react_1@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the react_1@0.1.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-11T12_59_30_892Z-debug.log
>
> C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Reaactapps\react_1>
> ```

Comment: [Due process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Due_process)? Like it needs to be read its [Miranda rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_warning)?

Comment: Learn how to work with errors. At first google what does `ENOENT` means, than how to resolve it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)