# NodeJS spawn a process without opening the shell

Tags: node.js, windows, child-process

I have a global npm package that I want to spawn as a process from a NodeJS application.

The problem is that on Windows 10 I have to use the property `shell: true`, otherwise I will receive the following error as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)

`Error: spawn pm2 ENOENT`

The problem is that I don't want to show a new shell on the UI when the command is executed, but rather to be a silent detached process.

[image]

My code is the following:

```
 const child: child_process.ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams = child_process.spawn(
    command,
    args,
    {
      shell: true,
      detached: true,
    },
  );
  child.unref();
```

**Mention**

I'm using node `v14.15.1` on a `Windows 10` machine.

I know that there is a property `windowsHide`, but this one is `true` by default and is still not working. The shell is still visible.

What should I do to spawn this detached process without showing a new shell on the os UI?

Comment: Why not solve the core issue instead of finding a workaround for a workaround. Requesting a console and then trying to hide the console doesn't sound like a solution to any problem.

Comment: Hi @IInspectable. Please read the question and the other question that is linked in the post. Without using the property shell:true is not working.

Comment: You will need a full path directly to the executable you are trying to run in order to run it without a shell.  Finding the executable via the path is something the shell does for you.