# I keep getting a installation error when I try to install any NPM package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

Lately, I found out that with every package I want to install I keep getting a error. Its always the same.

What I've tried:

- **Updating node/NPM**
- **Repairing node/NPM**
- **Fixing git bash in path variable.**
- **Deleting package-lock.json and running npm install**
- **Deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and running npm install.**
- **Clearing npm cache**
- **Manually creating the folder it says it can't find. However, this doesn't change anything.**
- **Manually adding the npm package to package-JSON. running npm install but again. results in an error.**

Packages installed fine at first. This has been like this for a week or 2.

short error:

```
    npm ERR! code ENOENT
    npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\Timsl\Documents\FarCryDiscordBot\node_modules\better-sqlite3
    npm ERR! errno -4058
    npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
    npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
    npm ERR! enoent
```

full log:
https://pastebin.com/1B4yLCLK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug "Error: spawn ENOENT" on node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js)

Comment: did you try running this command as an administrator?