# Issues running a next.js project on server

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am currently trying to run a project (simple test project) of next.js on a Linux server. The project is able to run locally no problem, however every time I run `npm run dev` or `npm run build` I get the following error:

```
node:events:368
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /nfs/encs/ArchDep/x86_64.EL7/pkg/node-v16.13.0/root/bin/node EAGAIN
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -11,
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'spawn /nfs/encs/ArchDep/x86_64.EL7/pkg/node-v16.13.0/root/bin/node',
  path: '/nfs/encs/ArchDep/x86_64.EL7/pkg/node-v16.13.0/root/bin/node',
  spawnargs: [
    '/nfs/www/groups/h/hn_comp353_2/comp353/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js'
  ]
}
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is a tricky error that can have many causes. Please consult the following SO Q&A resource that has many links on the topics: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js

Answer (score 3):

I see in your `spawnargs` that it's trying to execute `jest`, so this failure has something to do with your Jest tests not being able to run on your Linux server. This *may* be caused by Jest trying to spawn more threads than there are resources available on your server. This is pretty common on heavily virtualized environments where the resources are limited.

Can you try running Jest with either the [`--runInBand`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--runinband) or [`--maxWorkers=2`](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--maxworkersnumstring)? If you're running Jest through `npm` you'll have to add the command in your `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --runInBand"
  }
}
```

As a general remark, NodeJS `Error: spawn` errors are tricky to debug and can be caused by a variety of issues. There's another [SO Q&A with a lot of resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js) on this topic you can consult.