# How can I fix an error with the seed file in Prisma and typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, prisma

I'm building a backend using Prisma, Postgres 14.5, Node 18, and Typescript.
Every time try to seed the DB I get the following:

```
└ ➜ yarn prisma db seed
Environment variables loaded from .env
Running seed command `ts-node prisma/seed.ts` ...

An error occurred while running the seed command:
Error: Command failed with ENOENT: ts-node prisma/seed.ts
spawn ts-node ENOENT
```

ENOENT errors mean "No such file or directory"

I have this in my `package.json`:

```
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
  },
```

My seed file is located at `prisma/seed.ts` and contains:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function main() {
  const person = await prisma.name.upsert({
    where: { id: 0 },
    update: {},
    create: {
      firstName: 'Sakiko',
    },
  });
}

main()
  .then(async () => {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  })
  .catch(async (e) => {
    console.error(e);
    await prisma.$disconnect();
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: Can you try updating the file path like this. `./prisma/seed.ts`

Comment: @MCNaveen Good thought but I tried that and still got the same error

Comment: I'm not using ts. When I don't have that file I get a different error. This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js.

Comment: @shmuels Thanks, I was so focused on the seed file I didn't realize ENOENT was complaining about the missing command

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing `ts-node` as we don't have our build fully set up yet. So I fixed it with `yarn add ts-node`.

Additionally, I had to simplify our `tsconfig.json` to remove the `compilerOptions.rootDir` as the prisma code is outside the `src` directory.